# How can I iterate to a scala map in order to save the contents in a Seq?

Tags: scala, dictionary, seq

I have a scala map that stores a characters and their frequency in a string then I need to take the map and save all its contents into a Seq for example:

```
map[Char,int] = map[T,Int](a -> 3,b-> 2, c -> 1) => Seq[Char] = Seq[Char](a,a,a,b,b,c)
```

Anyone has any advice about how could I accomplish this or about how could I iterate through the map

Comment: Can you please write your expected values from the above example

Comment: What do you mean by that

Comment: Are you expecting final output as `Seq[Char](a,a,a,b,b,c)`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the Map and loop till frequency of chars and return the char for the same frequency inside the loop.

You can do something like this.

```
val x = Map('a' -> 3,'b' -> 2, 'c' -> 1)

x.flatMap {case(char,freq) =>
  (1 to freq).map(_ => char)
}.toSeq
```